# Custom views with web service calls in Android recycler view

Tags: android, listview, android-recyclerview, android-custom-view

I want to show a list like facebook news feed. I have a list of custom views, each one having a unique view layout and web request/response processing logic. These views were designed to be drag and drop ready; their container have no idea what goes on in those views. I have been using these views fine within all types of views (mostly ScrollView); except ListView/RecyclerView.

Recently there is a requirement where I have to put those views in an existing RecyclerView. Ideally, RecyclerView should make it's own web-service call with RecyclerView's adapter receiving a copy of data and a view holder for each child. But as I mentioned earlier, my custom views are making their own calls (thus adapter cannot have any data); and each view has it's own layout (thus view holder is useless).

So here's my question - when each of these views are recycled, is there a way to retain the data in the view ? Please note, I don't have a caching mechanism in my app. I was thinking of using `setTag()`, but then I realized `getTag()` will always return null on a recycled view. My goal is to initiate the web-service logic during view creation (in constructor) in `onCreateViewHolder()`. And then use the downloaded data in `onBindViewHolder()`.

Secondly, I don't know when to unregister the broadcast receiver listeners in the custom views (I use broadcasts to receive web-service responses from my network layer). For now I unregister in `onDetach()` of each view. I want to delay the unregister process until the view is ready for garbage collection; and `onDetach()` is called too soon.

I went through [this article](https://code.facebook.com/posts/879498888759525/fast-rendering-news-feed-on-android/) tackling a similar problem, but not very helpful. I am willing to change my design/architecture, if it helps.